# volume slider not working & how to connect playlist to listview

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, volume, playlist

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaMetaData
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QSlider
import glob
import os

list1=[]
song_list=[]


class Ui_MainWinpage(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWinpage):
        MainWinpage.setObjectName("MainWinpage")
        MainWinpage.resize(507, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWinpage)
        self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        # slider
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 160, 16))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue)
        self.horizontalSlider.setStyleSheet("background-color:royalblue;\n"
                                            "color: white;\n"
                                            "border-style: outset;\n"
                                            "border-width:2px;\n"
                                            "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                            "border-color:darkred;\n"
                                            "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                            "padding :6px;\n"
                                            "min-width:10px;\n"
                                            "\n"
                                            "\n"
                                            "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider, 0, 0, 1, 3)

        self.play_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.play_song.setObjectName("play_song")
        self.play_song.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                     "color: white;\n"
                                     "border-style: outset;\n"
                                     "border-width:2px;\n"
                                     "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                     "border-color:black;\n"
                                     "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                     "padding :6px;\n"
                                     "min-width:10px;\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.play_song, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pause_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pause_song.setObjectName("pause_song")
        self.pause_song.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                      "color: white;\n"
                                      "border-style: outset;\n"
                                      "border-width:2px;\n"
                                      "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                      "border-color:black;\n"
                                      "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                      "padding :6px;\n"
                                      "min-width:10px;\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "\n"
                                      "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pause_song, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.stop_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop_song.setObjectName("stop_song")
        self.stop_song.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                     "color: white;\n"
                                     "border-style: outset;\n"
                                     "border-width:2px;\n"
                                     "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                     "border-color:black;\n"
                                     "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                     "padding :6px;\n"
                                     "min-width:10px;\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "\n"
                                     "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stop_song, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.previous.setObjectName("previous")
        self.previous.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                    "color: white;\n"
                                    "border-style: outset;\n"
                                    "border-width:2px;\n"
                                    "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                    "border-color:black;\n"
                                    "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                    "padding :6px;\n"
                                    "min-width:10px;\n"
                                    "\n"
                                    "\n"
                                    "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.previous, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.shuffle = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.shuffle.setObjectName("shuffle")
        self.shuffle.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                   "color: white;\n"
                                   "border-style: outset;\n"
                                   "border-width:2px;\n"
                                   "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                   "border-color:black;\n"
                                   "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                   "padding :6px;\n"
                                   "min-width:10px;\n"
                                   "\n"
                                   "\n"
                                   "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.shuffle, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        self.next.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;\n"
                                "color: white;\n"
                                "border-style: outset;\n"
                                "border-width:2px;\n"
                                "border-radius:10px;\n"
                                "border-color:black;\n"
                                "font:bold 14px;\n"
                                "padding :6px;\n"
                                "min-width:10px;\n"
                                "\n"
                                "\n"
                                "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.next, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        # for volume
        self.volumeSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximum(32767)
        self.volumeSlider.setPageStep(1024)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.volumeSlider, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        # for listing in Sangeet mainwinpage
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(MainWinpage)
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")

        songs_mp3s = ['num1', 'num2', 'num3']
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(model)

        for i in songs_mp3s:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)
            model.appendRow(item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listView, 5, 1, 1, 1)

        MainWinpage.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWinpage)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 507, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menufile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menufile.setObjectName("menufile")
        MainWinpage.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWinpage)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWinpage.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionopen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWinpage)
        self.actionopen.setObjectName("actionopen")
        self.menufile.addAction(self.actionopen)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menufile.menuAction())

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWinpage)

        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        # for Qtmultimedia
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.changeVolume)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWinpage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWinpage)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWinpage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWinpage.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWinpage", "Sangeet"))
        self.play_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "play"))
        self.pause_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "pause"))
        self.stop_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "stop"))
        self.previous.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "previous"))
        self.shuffle.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "playlist"))
        self.next.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "next"))
        self.menufile.setTitle(_translate("MainWinpage", "file"))
        self.actionopen.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "open "))

        self.previous.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "Browse"))
        self.previous.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_handler)
        self.play_song.clicked.connect(self.play_music)
        self.pause_song.clicked.connect(self.pause_music)
        self.stop_song.clicked.connect(self.stop_music)
        self.shuffle.clicked.connect(self.playlist_handler)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        blocked = self.media_player.blockSignals(True)
        value = self.horizontalSlider.value()
        self.media_player.setPosition(value)
        self.media_player.blockSignals(blocked)

    def changeVolume(self, value):
        self.volumeSlider.volume = value
        self.volumeSlider.setVolume.durationChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum)
        self.volumeSlider.value.positionChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
        print("volume is:", value)

    def filebrowser(self, ext=""):
        return [f for f in glob.glob(f"*{ext}")]

    def calc(self):
        self.filebrowser()
        x = self.filebrowser(".mp3")
        y = len(x)
        print("number of items in list-", y)
        for w in x:
            song_list.append(w)
            print(w)

    def pushButton_handler(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.open_dialog_box()

    def playlist_handler(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.open_dialog_box_for_playlist()

        # for opening that file which you want to open

    def open_dialog_box(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = str(filename[0])
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        print("path is ", path)
        self.globalpath = path
        print("global paths is ", self.globalpath)

    def open_dialog_box_for_playlist(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        path = str(filename)
        # self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        # print("path is ",path)
        # self.global_playlist_path = path
        # print("global paths is ", self.global_playlist_path)
        self.getFolderPlaylist(path)
        # self.calc()

        # path = '/home/darshan/Sangeet/pyqtlayout'
        # for list of songs in folder

    def getFolderPlaylist(self, paths):
        ls = os.listdir(paths)
        list_songs_mp3s=[]
        for item in ls:
            if item.count('mp3'):
                list_songs_mp3s.append(item)

        if len(list_songs_mp3s) > 0:
            folderName = os.path.basename(paths)
            print("mp3s are--", list_songs_mp3s)
            return folderName, paths, list_songs_mp3s
        else:
            return None

        # for playing that file which we had choosen from

    def play_music(self):
        artist = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.AlbumArtist)
        title = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.Title)
        self.media_player.play()
        print("song name:", self.globalpath)
        print(f"Now playing: {title} by {artist}")

        # for pause that selected music

    def pause_music(self):
        self.media_player.pause()
        print("song is paused")

        # for stoping that music

    def stop_music(self):
        self.media_player.stop()
        print("song is stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWinpage = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWinpage()
    ui.setupUi(MainWinpage)
    MainWinpage.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines don't make any sense:

```
self.volumeSlider.setVolume.durationChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum)
self.volumeSlider.value.positionChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
```

You would have found that by yourself if you tried to run it in a shell/command prompt (but your IDE should have warned you about it anyway).

As already pointed out in a comment to your previous question, QSlider has **no** `setVolume` attribute, and `value` is a *property* that has to be called (`self.volumeSlider.value()`), it returns the current slider value as an integer, and integers have no `positionChanged` attribute.

Change the function to this:

```
def changeVolume(self, value):
    self.media_player.setVolume(value / self.volumeSlider.maximum() * 100)
```

The formula is: compute the ratio of the current value based on the full extent of the slider (`value / maximum`) and then multiply it by 100, since QMediaPlayer accepts values as percentages.

Carefully study the documentation about [QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html) and its base class, [QAbstractSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html).

Finally, never use the python files generated by `pyuic` to create your programs. *NEVER*.
They *must* be used as imported modules, and your program should be created in a separate file. Read the documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to know more.

Comment: thankyou sir musicamante for helping me now my volume slider is working very properly